# Dagger 2 Update base url in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger-2

I am creating a new MVP project, and using Dagger 2 along with Retrofit, But I am facing this issue where the app is supposed to get the base URL from the server and start calling network APIs.

The problem here is that I could not update the URL at run-time!
The best solution I came up with was to update the URL, but at next run of the app!

I tried many ideas and solutions that existed on StackOverFlow but none of them worked!

```
private final Application mApplication;
private String mBaseUrl;


public ApplicationModule(Application application, String baseUrl) {
    mApplication = application;
    mBaseUrl = baseUrl;
}


@Provides
@Singleton
OkHttpClient providesOkHttpClient() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    client.readTimeout(Constants.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(Constants.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return client.build();
}


@Provides
@RetrofitGSON
Retrofit providesRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder()
                            .setPrettyPrinting()
                            .create()
                    )
            )
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For all who are having this kind of problem, here is how to solve it.
you need to override okhttp Interceptor.

```
@Singleton
public class ExampleInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private static ExampleInterceptor sInterceptor;
    private String mScheme;
    private String mHost;

    @Inject
    public static ExampleInterceptor get() {
        if (sInterceptor == null) {
            sInterceptor = new ExampleInterceptor();
         }
      return sInterceptor;
    }

    private ExampleInterceptor() {
         // Intentionally blank
    }

    public void setInterceptor(String url) {
        HttpUrl httpUrl = HttpUrl.parse(url);
        mScheme = httpUrl.scheme();
        mHost = httpUrl.host();
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        // If new Base URL is properly formatted than replace with old one
        if (mScheme != null && mHost != null) {
            HttpUrl newUrl = original.url().newBuilder()
                .scheme(mScheme)
                .host(mHost)
                .build();
        original = original.newBuilder()
                .url(newUrl)
                .build();
        }
     return chain.proceed(original);
    }
}
```